# A sublime text's .sublime-project file does not affect my project

Tags: sublimetext2

Here is a weird one. I have this .sublime-project

```
{
    "font_size": 18.0,
    "font_face": "Arial",
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/Users/bertuz/Documents/università/thesis/thesis/doc",
            "file_exlude_patterns" : [
                "*.pdf"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but: I can see all the PDF in my project dir, plus the font is not modified, neither is the size. I've tried to close and reopen the project of course, without any effect. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the settings into an object with a "settings" key, and you misspelled "file_exclude_patterns"

```
{
    "settings": {
        "font_size": 18.0,
        "font_face": "Arial",
    },

    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/Users/bertuz/Documents/università/thesis/thesis/doc",
            "file_exclude_patterns" : [
                "*.pdf"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```